# How to export an Client Object to another file in WhatsAppWeb JS Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp

How to export an Client Object to another file in WhatsAppWeb JS Library . I need this so that the client is always connected and i can make function calls with this client and it runs faster without waiting for client to connect for every functions call.